# Qt Drag and Drop - Change image display while dragging

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, drag-and-drop

I started a drag with image.

```
QDrag* drag = new(QDrag)(this);
drag->setPixmap(*pixmap);
drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction);
```

I want to change the image display when my drag reach certain point in the widget.

Currently I have an idea. After I start the first drag, when my drag reaches a certain point, I cancel the first drag then I restart a new drag with a new image.

I do this in `dragMoveEvent`. I'm able to start a new drag with a new image. But I seem to be unable to cancel the first drag. I find that the the previous drag/drop action is still being performed.

Anyone could suggest:

```
if (event->mimeData()->hasText())
{
  if (need_to_change_pixmap())
  {
    event->setDropAction(Qt::IgnoreAction);
    change_pixmap_restart_drag();
  }
  else
  {
    event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
    event->accept();
  }
}
else
{
  event->ignore();
}
```

The **`change_pixmap_restart_drag`** function just do start drag.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Qt's documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdrag.html#setPixmap), you can't change the pixmap once the dragging has started.

Qt uses:

- a frameless windows which follow the mouse **on X11**. The pixmap is painted on the widget, and `setGrabMouse` is used to receive mouse events, since the widget is not directly under the mouse.
- the function `SetCursor` **on Windows**, with a copy of the pixmap where the cursors for each action has been painted in the corner.
- the function `SetDragImageWithCGImage` **on Mac**, but needs a `DragRef` object which is declared as an inaccessible local variable in *qdnd_mac.mm*.

You could try to use the X11 method on all platforms, or use `SetCursor` if you only plan to deploy your application on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From QDrag docs:

```
void QDrag::setPixmap ( const QPixmap & pixmap ) :
```

Sets **`pixmap`** as the `pixmap` used to represent the data in a drag and drop operation. You can only set a `pixmap` before the drag is started.

So, I'm sorry, but you can't!
Even **`setDragCursor()`** is a method with no effects...